# error: C compiler cannot create executables (GEOS, basemap)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, executable, matplotlib-basemap, geos

I am currently getting the following error when attempting to get `basemap-1.0.7` to work on my MAC OS v10.7.3:

```
error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I downloaded `basemap-1.0.7.tar.gz` from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib-toolkits/basemap-1.0.7/), and upon installation, I followed the numbered instructions in the README file:

> 0) Install pre-requisite python modules numpy and matplotlib.
>
> 1) Then download basemap-X.Y.Z.tar.gz (approx 100 mb) from
>      the sourceforge download site, unpack and cd to basemap-X.Y.Z.
>
> 2) Install the GEOS library.  If you already have it on your
>      system, just set the environment variable GEOS_DIR to point to the location 
>      of libgeos_c and geos_c.h (if libgeos_c is in /usr/local/lib and
>      geos_c.h is in /usr/local/include, set GEOS_DIR to /usr/local).
>      Then go to step (3).  If you don't have it, you can build it from
>      the source code included with basemap by following these steps:
>
> ```
> > cd geos-3.3.3
> > export GEOS_DIR=<where you want the libs and headers to go>
>   A reasonable choice on a Unix-like system is /usr/local, or
>   if you don't have permission to write there, your home directory.
> > ./configure --prefix=$GEOS_DIR 
> > make; make install
> ```

**0) Done**: I use `anaconda`, so both `import numpy` and `import matplotlib` work in an interactive session of `ipython`.

**1) Done**: basemap 1.0.7 is downloaded, unpacked, and I have changed my working directory to to `Downloads/basemap-1.0.7/`

**2) Problem**: I do *not* have the GEOS library. Therefore, I followed the instructions as per the README file:

```
cd geos-3.3.3 
export GEOS_DIR=/Users/ged/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
./configure --prefix=$GEOS_DIR
```

The ensuing terminal output is:

```
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no    
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/ged/Downloads/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

The `config.log` file is a bit long to put it here, so I've made it available [here](http://pastebin.com/EEEs9Duy)

I have tried installing GEOS through GDAL 1.11, and I also looked into upgrading to `xcode 4.6.3` but, to be honest, I feel a little out of my depth.

I'm getting the following message:

```
error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Could you please provide some insight on how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to post the 10-20 lines logged around the error message in `config.log`. That message itself says nothing about the actual problem.

Comment: I went ahead and replaced the dropbox link with a pastebin one so it's easier/faster for people to view the log

Comment: Can you run `gcc` from the command line and compile a small program?

Comment: The most interesting lines of config.log are `configure:3159: found /usr/local/bin/gcc` ... `gcc (GCC) 4.5.0 20090910 (experimental)` ... `gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory`

Comment: n.m: I do not know how to run `gcc` from the command line and compile a small program.